# How to create a dynamic query in a local report(.rdlc) in c#

Tags: c#, sdf, localreport, dynamic-queries

In my application I have 3 report.rdlc files that records are not different
I am creating a query in a form with options buttons, checkboxes and combobox values

```
string qry = "";
SqlCeConnection cnn = new 

SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString.ToString());
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();

    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        qry = @"Select Did,Cid,Source,Destination,Sid,cost,sdate,Driver.fname+' '+Driver.lname as driver,payed from Service,Driver where Service.Did=Driver.id";
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        button3.Enabled = true;
        qry = @"Select Did,Cid,Source,Destination,Sid,cost,sdate,Driver.fname+' '+Driver.lname as driver,payed from Service,Driver where Service.Did=Driver.id and Did=@param ";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", CmbDriver.SelectedValue);
    }

    if (payedRB.Checked == true)
    {
        qry += @" and Service.payed=1";
    }
    else if (notpayedRB.Checked == true)
    {
        qry += @" and Service.payed=0";
    }

    if (txtDate1.Text != "" && txtDate2.Text != "")
    {
        qry += @" and Service.sdate between @pdate1 AND @pdate2";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdate1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtDate1.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdate2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtDate2.Text.Trim();
        state = 3;
    }
    else if (txtDate1.Text != "")
    {
        qry += @" and Service.sdate >= @pdate1";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdate1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtDate1.Text.Trim();
        state = 1;
    }
    else if (txtDate2.Text != "")
    {
        qry += @" and Service.sdate <= @pdate2";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdate2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtDate2.Text.Trim();
        state = 2;
    }

    if (activdr.Checked == true)
    {
        qry += @" and Driver.isActive=1";
    }
    else
    {
        qry += @" and Driver.isActive=0";
    }

    qry += @" ORDER BY Service.sdate desc,Service.Sid desc";

    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);


                cnn.Open();

                adapter.Fill(dt);......
```

I used reporttype variable in option buttons event to know which
report will be shown in report viewer. and set selected records to
data grid viewer

my reports get data from a temp table that is compatible with record's
field. before this I insert all records( that will be printed in the report
viewer) into temp table;

How can I transfer **records** into reports without temp table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In local reports it is *not possible* to have the report itself query the database. Your application needs to query the database and pass the results to the report as a data source.

You need to fill a data set now and pass this as a `DataSource` to the report. The report needs to define a respective data source to provide values for the fields.

Comment: I have dt datatable in my code.now How can i pass this datatable to the local report such as any table in database by datasource and dataset.or other ways? please tell me references or code.. Thanks so much

Comment: Did you google? The search words "c# rdlc dataset" show up at least 4 results here on StackOverflow.