# Display rdlc report with more than one dataset -c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a desktop app (winforms) with an embedded Local Database SQL CE .

I have 2 tables in my database: Customers and Orders.

In Customers table I have : customerID , customerName.

In Orders table I have : CustomerID , OrderID, OrderName.

I want to display a report  with : CustomerID , CustomerName , OrderName.

How can I get the value for customerName that matches the customerID in ordersTable.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomersName, Orders.OrderName
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you're using local report (*.rdlc types) it is not possible to set
>   custom query for report. you can create a report table and insert
>   searched records in it and make a local report for report table!! or
>   use dynamic query dataset.

I had this problem before: [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062282/how-to-create-a-dynamic-query-in-a-local-report-rdlc-in-c-sharp)